# How to properly use DownloadSecureFile task with self-hosted Mac agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have created yaml pipelines in TFS to build and sign Android and iOS. For building I use self-hosted Mac Agent. The build runs successfully, but once I add [DownloadSecureFile task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to yaml and try to download certificate or provisioning profiles from "Secure files" I got this error:

> ##[error]Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

I checked our self-hosted agent during build time and certificates or profiles were downloaded successfully. It seems like for some reason agent checks whether files are trusted or not. Is there any way how to disable this check?

I was trying to do in the past the same thing on [hosted build agent from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and it worked fine. I was able to download secure file, sign and build the app.